# MSI needs to replace files that are in use. Schedules removal, fails to replace and then file is missing

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I have an application that needs to upgrade itself, so it runs an MSI that installs the application while the application is still running.  For years that has worked successfully, despite the .exe's, .dll's and other things being in use the installer works without a problem.  However I am now installing the CEF browser component and this is causing me trouble.

This is an example from the installer log:

```
    *** the file is scheduled for removal
    MSI (s) (9C:7C) [11:44:06:372]: Executing op: FileRemove(,FileName=cef.pak,,ComponentId={AEDD9CDD-C5CB-4260-A5D5-A7C13011CC97})
    MSI (s) (9C:7C) [11:44:06:374]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    MSI (s) (9C:7C) [11:44:06:374]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    MSI (s) (9C:7C) [11:44:06:374]: Using source file security for destination.
    MSI (s) (9C:7C) [11:44:06:375]: Note: 1: 2318 2: C:\Config.Msi\144c57.rbf 
    MSI (s) (9C:7C) [11:44:06:390]: Note: 1: 2329 2: 32 3: C:\xxxx\cef.pak 
    MSI (s) (9C:7C) [11:44:06:390]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    MSI (s) (9C:7C) [11:44:06:393]: Executing op: FileRemove(,FileName=cef_100_percent.pak,,ComponentId={AEDD9CDD-C5CB-4260-A5D5-A7C13011CC97})
    Info 1903. Scheduling reboot operation: Deleting file C:\xxxx\cef.pak. Must reboot to complete operation.

    *** The file is not overwritten and it sees the files as the same
    MSI (s) (9C:30) [11:44:09:050]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=cef.pak,SourceCabKey=cef.pak,DestName=cef.pak,Attributes=512,FileSize=1961473,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=58982400,HashOptions=0,HashPart1=885556701,HashPart2=2067920947,HashPart3=-336625845,HashPart4=-1380829775,,)
    MSI (s) (9C:30) [11:44:09:056]: File: C:\xxxxcef.pak;   Won't Overwrite;    Won't patch;    Existing file is unversioned and unmodified - hash matches source file
```

So the installer tries to remove the file, knows it is in use and schedules a remove after the reboot.  But then it sees if it should install the file, sees it is already there (it hasn't been removed yet) and decides to not do anything.  So after the reboot the file is gone and the application fails.

I tried setting the installer to always replace the file with:

```
<Property Id='REINSTALLMODE' Value='amus'/>
```

On Windows 7 this produces the desired behaviour, the file is seen as being in use, the new one is copied to a temporary location and a rename scheduled for after a reboot and delete.

```
    Line 1525: MSI (s) (CC:64) [12:19:41:201]: The file represented by File table key 'cef.pak' has no eligible binary patches
    Line 2618: MSI (s) (CC:64) [12:19:41:775]: Executing op: FileRemove(,FileName=cef.pak,,ComponentId={AEDD9CDD-C5CB-4260-A5D5-A7C13011CC97})
    Line 2619: MSI (s) (CC:64) [12:19:41:776]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    Line 2620: MSI (s) (CC:64) [12:19:41:776]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    Line 2622: MSI (s) (CC:64) [12:19:41:779]: Note: 1: 2329 2: 32 3: C:\xxx\cef.pak 
    Line 2623: MSI (s) (CC:64) [12:19:41:779]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    Line 2625: Info 1903. Scheduling reboot operation: Deleting file C:\xxx\cef.pak. Must reboot to complete operation.
    Line 3382: MSI (s) (CC:68) [12:19:42:632]: The file represented by File table key 'cef.pak' has no eligible binary patches
    Line 3801: MSI (s) (CC:68) [12:19:42:933]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=cef.pak,SourceCabKey=cef.pak,DestName=cef.pak,Attributes=512,FileSize=1961473,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=62914560,HashOptions=0,HashPart1=885556701,HashPart2=2067920947,HashPart3=-336625845,HashPart4=-1380829775,,)
    Line 3801: MSI (s) (CC:68) [12:19:42:933]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=cef.pak,SourceCabKey=cef.pak,DestName=cef.pak,Attributes=512,FileSize=1961473,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=62914560,HashOptions=0,HashPart1=885556701,HashPart2=2067920947,HashPart3=-336625845,HashPart4=-1380829775,,)
    Line 3801: MSI (s) (CC:68) [12:19:42:933]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=cef.pak,SourceCabKey=cef.pak,DestName=cef.pak,Attributes=512,FileSize=1961473,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=62914560,HashOptions=0,HashPart1=885556701,HashPart2=2067920947,HashPart3=-336625845,HashPart4=-1380829775,,)
    Line 3802: MSI (s) (CC:68) [12:19:42:939]: File: C:\xxx\cef.pak;    Overwrite;  Won't patch;    REINSTALLMODE specifies all files to be overwritten
    Line 3803: MSI (s) (CC:68) [12:19:42:939]: Source for file 'cef.pak' is compressed
    Line 3805: MSI (s) (CC:68) [12:19:43:713]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    Line 3806: MSI (s) (CC:68) [12:19:43:713]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    Line 3808: MSI (s) (CC:68) [12:19:43:717]: Note: 1: 2329 2: 32 3: C:\xxx\cef.pak 
    Line 3809: MSI (s) (CC:68) [12:19:43:717]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    Line 3810: Info 1603. The file C:\xxx\cef.pak is being held in use. Close that application and retry.
    Line 3811: Info 1903. Scheduling reboot operation: Deleting file C:\xxx\cef.pak. Must reboot to complete operation.
    Line 3812: Info 1902. Scheduling reboot operation: Renaming file C:\xxx\TBMBFB2.tmp to C:\xxx\cef.pak. Must reboot to complete operation.
```

In Windows 10 however this does not occur, it tries to immediately replace the file without using the temporary file and it therefore fails.

```
cef.pak
    Line 1895: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:12:133]: The file represented by File table key 'cef.pak' has no eligible binary patches
    Line 3011: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:13:761]: Executing op: FileRemove(,FileName=cef.pak,,ComponentId={AEDD9CDD-C5CB-4260-A5D5-A7C13011CC97})
    Line 3012: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:13:763]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    Line 3013: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:13:764]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    Line 3016: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:13:782]: Note: 1: 2329 2: 32 3: c:\xxx\cef.pak 
    Line 3017: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:13:782]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    Line 3019: Info 1903. Scheduling reboot operation: Deleting file c:\xxx\cef.pak. Must reboot to complete operation.
    Line 3747: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:16:042]: The file represented by File table key 'cef.pak' has no eligible binary patches
    Line 4322: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:16:577]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=cef.pak,SourceCabKey=cef.pak,DestName=cef.pak,Attributes=512,FileSize=1961473,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=62914560,HashOptions=0,HashPart1=885556701,HashPart2=2067920947,HashPart3=-336625845,HashPart4=-1380829775,,)
    Line 4322: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:16:577]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=cef.pak,SourceCabKey=cef.pak,DestName=cef.pak,Attributes=512,FileSize=1961473,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=62914560,HashOptions=0,HashPart1=885556701,HashPart2=2067920947,HashPart3=-336625845,HashPart4=-1380829775,,)
    Line 4322: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:16:577]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=cef.pak,SourceCabKey=cef.pak,DestName=cef.pak,Attributes=512,FileSize=1961473,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=62914560,HashOptions=0,HashPart1=885556701,HashPart2=2067920947,HashPart3=-336625845,HashPart4=-1380829775,,)
    Line 4323: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:16:584]: File: c:\xxx\cef.pak;    Overwrite;  Won't patch;    REINSTALLMODE specifies all files to be overwritten
    Line 4324: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:16:584]: Source for file 'cef.pak' is compressed
    Line 4325: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:16:585]: Re-applying security from existing file.
    Line 4326: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:645]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    Line 4327: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:647]: Using source file security for destination.
    Line 4328: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:647]: Note: 1: 2318 2: C:\Config.Msi\a5880.rbf 
    Line 4329: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:651]: Note: 1: 1310 2: 0 3: c:\xxx\cef.pak 
    Line 4330: Info 1603. The file c:\xxx\cef.pak is being held in use. Close that application and retry.
    Line 4331: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:652]: Product: XXX-- Error 1310. Error writing to file: c:\xxx\cef.pak.  System error 0.  Verify that you have access to that directory.
    Line 4332: 
    Line 4333: Error 1310. Error writing to file: c:\xxx\cef.pak.  System error 0.  Verify that you have access to that directory.
    Line 4334: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:683]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 
    Line 4335: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:684]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
    Line 4336: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:684]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
    Line 4337: Action ended 12:07:21: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
    Line 4347: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:713]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=C:\Config.Msi\a5880.rbf,,DestName=c:\xxx\cef.pak,Attributes=32,FileSize=0,PerTick=0,,VerifyMedia=0,ElevateFlags=3,,,,,,,InstallMode=4194304,,,,,,,)
    Line 4348: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:713]: File: c:\xxx\cef.pak;    Overwrite;  Won't patch;    REINSTALLMODE specifies all files to be overwritten
    Line 4349: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:715]: Re-applying security from existing file.
    Line 4350: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:718]: Note: 1: 2318 2:  
    Line 4351: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:720]: Verifying accessibility of file: cef.pak
    Line 4352: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:722]: Using source file security for destination.
    Line 4353: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:722]: Note: 1: 2318 2: C:\Config.Msi\a5881.rbf 
    Line 4354: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:735]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
    Line 4355: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:737]: Note: 1: 1310 2: 32 3: c:\xxx\cef.pak 
    Line 4356: Info 1603. The file c:\xxx\cef.pak is being held in use. Close that application and retry.
    Line 4357: MSI (s) (88:8C) [12:07:21:737]: Error in rollback skipped.   Return: 3
    Line 4358: Info 1310. Error writing to file: c:\xxx\cef.pak.  System error 32.  Verify that you have access to that directory.
```

Is there a way to get that behaviour for other types of files (e.g .pak files)?

Answer (score 1):

***CEF Browser***: I am not familiar with this component. Does it run in-process? (as a dll) - or does it have an API-call to shut itself down? Could you try to implement the Windows Restart Manager **`"RegisterApplicationRestart"`** feature described below for your main executable? Or you can call shutdown in a custom action for the component if there is an API?

***Data File***: Also, is this a data file that you should not install at all, but rather let the component itself create on launch? If this is the case you can remove the file from the installer and avoid it being entangled with your installer at all? This is particularly preferable for unversioned files - which can be hard to update beacuse of the [MSI file overwrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48651809/129130) / [file versioning rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/file-versioning-rules).

---

[***Restart Manager***](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/windows/win32/rstmgr/restart-manager-portal): Windows Installer supports what is referred to as a [Restart Manager feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917062/windows-installer-avoid-fileinuse-dialog-box-when-installing-a-package/50935008#50935008). The idea is to have the application shut itself down gracefully during installation - releasing all file and resource locks - and then to have Windows Installer restart it again after all files have been updated. This means that the application itself will take care of its own shutdown and restart when told to do so: `"shut yourself down and restart when told"` (saving all data and ideally the exact state). Only the application itself can know how to do this properly?

***Technical Support***: This is a technical article on how to implement support for the [Restart Manager feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917062/windows-installer-avoid-fileinuse-dialog-box-when-installing-a-package/50935008#50935008) in your application - from Advanced Installer, makers of leading deployment tools. It is a nice article: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-vista-restart-manager.html

```
HRESULT WINAPI RegisterApplicationRestart(PCWSTR pwzCommandline, DWORD dwFlags);
```

The whole idea is basically to prefer restarting applications rather than restarting the OS - and also to avoid reboots in general. To that end: **`1)`** Your application calls **`RegisterApplicationRestart()`** with a command line specified for its eventual restart - it "signs up" for restart management. **`2)`** Your application watches for **`WM_QUERYENDSESSION messages`** and shuts down gracefully saving data in an appropriate way when told to do so. **`3)`** Then Restart Manager can restart the application when finished installing (restart can be disabled).

---

***Links:***

- [Restart Manager and rebooting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48842663/129130)
- [Restart Manager guidelines for applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rstmgr/guidelines-for-applications)